# Typedef missing type specifier

Tags: c

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

#define internal static
#define local_persist static
#define global_variable static

#define false 0
#define true 1

typedef int8_t int8;
typedef int16_t int16;
typedef int32_t int32;
typedef int64_t int64;
typedef int32 bool32;

typedef uint32_t uint32;

void Update(void);
void Render(void);

>------ Build started: Project: Shattered, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  main.c
1>  shattered.cpp
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(12): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'int8'
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(13): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'int16'
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(14): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'int32'
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(15): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'int64'
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(15): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(16): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'bool32'
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(16): error C2378: 'int32' : redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef
1>          c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(14) : see declaration of 'int32'
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(18): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'uint32'
1>c:\users\zak\desktop\shattered\shattered\shattered.h(18): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So this is my code the output i am getting is saying that it does not know the type of int8, when i clearly included stdio.h.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What compiler are you using? What system are you compiling on?

Comment: I think you mean `typedef int8 int8_t;`

Comment: `#include <stdint.h>`, tossing `int8_t` in a google search box will tell you which header it is declared in (along with all the others).

Comment: If this is C++, don't redefine `true` and `false`. If this is C, you should probably be including `stdbool.h` for them if possible.

Comment: `stdint.h` types like `int32_t` are surprisingly defined in `stdint.h`. `bool` & friends are defined in `stdbool.h`. You really should not define those on your own! And the `#define`s are really missleading. Do not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `#include <stdint.h>` which has definitions for those types.

Comment: Omg i feel so dumb. I swore i wrote stdint. Thanks